# How to communicate with qt c++ and Plc programming twincat beckhoff

Tags: visual-studio-code, qt-creator, twincat, twincat-ads, ethercat

I'm running beckhoff Ep 2809-0022 I/O in plc .how I will communicate with plc an qt c++ in UDP socket communication particular I want to show in UI in qt environment

I'm running beckhoff Ep 2809-0022 I/O in c++

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use socket comms with a PLC in Beckhoff you need to check out TF6310 [link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6310_tc3_tcpip/index.html&id=9025637582166106076), for access in Beckhoff's C++ module you can only use TF6311 [link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6311_tc3_tcpudp/index.html&id=9004581143610845071). However, I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do from your question, if you only want to talk to the PLC using C++ I would recommend using the Beckhoff ADS for comms to the PLC when making a UI, check out the C driver [link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_adsdll2/index.html&id=4279787267115190858)